# Check if Type is DateTime

Tags: c#

I have a function that checks if a type is a DateTime type:

```
    public static bool IsDateTime(Type myType)
    {
        return myType is DateTime; // compilation error
    }
```

but this gives error:

> The given expression is never of the provided type ('System.DateTime')

Passing argument 'myType' as object instead of Type would work but I am trying to do it without the need of changing it.

I am using standard ASP.NET Framework 4.5

Comment: you can use `return myType==typeof(DateTime);`

Comment: `myType == typeof(DateTime);`

Comment: @Mofid.Moghimi it works thanks.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes, it answers perfectly, Great link. Many thanks.